# Ecto Referencing Another Schema During Migration for Foreign-Key Relationship

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

We are working with a schema-based multi-tenancy database. We are on an Elixir stack, using Postgres, Ecto, and Triplex within a Phoenix Framework project.

We are using the default schema `public` to store common data, such as users and organisations. In particular, we have within the `Organisations` table a `tenant_prefix` column which we use to map a user to their tenancy.

Within a tenancy, we tenant-specific tables. As an example, we have a `Products` table. When a new organisation is created, we use Triplex to create the schema and run tenant migrations, which create the tenant-specific tables such as `Products`.

As a visual, the database looks like this:

```
- app_database
  - public
    - users
    - organisations
    - organisations_users

  - tenant1
    - products
    - (other tables...)

  - tenant2
     - products
     - (other tables...)
```

The `Products` migration looks like this.

```
 1 defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateProducts do
 2  use Ecto.Migration
 3
 4  def change do
 5    create table(:products) do
 6      add :title, :string
 7      add :description, :string
 8      add :organisation_id, references(:organisations, on_delete: :nothing), null: false
 9
10      timestamps()
11    end
12
13    create index(:products, [:organisation_id])
14  end
15 end
```

Right now, it is failing to run because of the `Line 8`. The erorr that is reported is: `ERROR 42P01 (undefined_table) relation "59ef85c702d24d0fac5c7e425d0d3d44.organisations" does not exist`

The tenant prefix is a UUID.

So to summarise, we are wondering how to reference the `public.organisations` table to define the foreign key relationship in `tenant.products`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if it helps but I think that you should be using `prefix` option with your references. You can checkout the docs for further references.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2

As of my understanding line 8 should be something like this

```
add :organisation_id, references(:organisations, on_delete: :nothing, prefix: "public"), null: false
```

As for the syntax, use `:public` if `"public"` results in a syntax error.

**Why you need this?**

Normally when prefix defaults to nil and in that case ecto certainly prefixes your current schema name with the table name, which is happening in your case. By setting this prefix option you can set a custom value based on your requirements.

Please do comment if it works. Since I am also curious...

Comment: That was it. Thanks!